# Find the least possible value for $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For Positive $m$ and $n$, the decimal representation for the fraction $\frac {m}{n}$

begins $0.711$ and followed by other digits. Find the least possible value for $n$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: A computer search shows that the solution with smallest $n$ is $\frac{32}{45}$.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Begin with $\frac 01=0.000$ and $\frac11=1.000$.

Step 2: You have $\frac ab<0.711<0.712\le\frac cd$ and $ad-bc=-1$, compute $\frac ef=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$.

Step 3: If $0.711\le \frac ef<0.712$, you are done. $n=f$ is the answer.

Step 4: Otherwise, if $\frac ef<0.711$, replace $\frac ab$ with $\frac ef$. Otherwise, if $\frac ef\ge 0.712$, replace $\frac cd$ with $\frac ef$. Return to step 2.

Answer (score 0):

I started off with $0.711 \leq \frac{m}{n} < 0.712$.

However, I quickly gave up and wrote a program.

It is $\frac{32}{45}$.